# Make work rtl8187 and ath10k together

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I have a problem since I have made work my Killer Wireless-AC 1525 working with Ubuntu. I have followed those instructions (#209): 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184

I have installed dkms: `sudo apt-get install dkms`
Then I have downloaded the .deb and have run it: 
`sudo dpkg --install ath10k-dkms_1.0_all.deb`

Now my internal wireless card works perfectly. However, when I plug other wireless adapters (realtek adapters for example) they do not work anymore.

I can see it `lsusb` : `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8187 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187 Wireless Adapter`

I have the module `modinfo rtl8187` : `filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-33-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
license:        GPL
description:    RTL8187/RTL8187B USB wireless driver
author:         Larry Finger <Larry.Finger@lwfinger.net>
author:         Hin-Tak Leung <htl10@users.sourceforge.net>
author:         Herton Ronaldo Krzesinski <herton@mandriva.com.br>
author:         Andrea Merello <andrea.merello@gmail.com>
author:         Michael Wu <flamingice@sourmilk.net>`

But I cannot see it with `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`. And when I want to use `sudo modprobe rtl8187` I get the error : `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8187': Invalid argument`

Is there a way to make realtek (and why not all others) driver works again without cancel the ath10k modification.

By the way `Linux  3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the DKMS package you installed is that it only supports the ath10k module using backports.  You could uninstall the ath10k-dkms and then install another backports package

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz
```

tar -zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz
sudo dpkg -r ath10k-dkms

Reboot

```
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Removing the ath10k-dkms file also removes the firmware, we can reinstall the firmware by

```
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/ /lib/firmware/ath10k/
```

And add the parameter setting with

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
```

If you have an error with `sudo dpkg -r ath10k-dkms` you might have to use `sudo dpkg -r ath10k-dkms --all` to remove it then reboot and continue with the instructions.

After a new kernel is installed through updates you will have to

```
cd backports-20151120
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Then reboot unless the new kernel supports the Killer wireless 1525

If I remember correctly the ath10k-dkms was done by Adam Lee and I understand why he did it the way it was done as DKMS makes you have a few entries in dkms.conf for every module you want to use and there would be a lot of work involved to make it support every wireless module supported by backports.

Reboot and both wireless cards should function

Comment: I have tried your procedure.  
At the `sudo make install` I have strange messages like :

`...
  INSTALL /home/f0cks/Downloads/backports-20151120/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
Can't read private key
  INSTALL /home/f0cks/Downloads/backports-20151120/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
Can't read private key
...`
Now usb adapters work again but not my Killer anymore :/

Comment: The Can't read private key is normal, I will edit for the rest

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have followed again the whole procedure including the new firmware but I still have not my killer in `ifconfig` ...

Comment: What does `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` show now?

Comment: It shows : 
`02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0685]
 Kernel driver in use: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:003e] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1525]
 Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5227] (rev 01)`

Comment: `ls /etc/modprobe.d/ | grep -i ath` as I bet it removed the needed parameter and then `echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf` Reboot

Comment: `blacklist-ath_pci.conf` what should I do with that?
Hey I have just  `echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=Y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf` And know both are working!!!
You saved me thanks a lot!

Comment: I will clean up the mess in my answer for anyone else that might want to have more than one device working with the ath10k-dkms